# Regarding ajax response after success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am confused about get rid from "[]" brackets after the ajax response data. I have the ajax response coming like:

```
[{"summary":"9am Smith Velarde - Alejandro DDT CMC","location":"","start":{"dateTime":"2018-02-27 09:00:00"},"end":{"dateTime":"2018-02-27 10:00:00"}}]
```

But i want the above response like:

```
{"summary":"9am Smith Velarde - Alejandro DDT CMC","location":"","start":{"dateTime":"2018-02-27 09:00:00"},"end":{"dateTime":"2018-02-27 10:00:00"}}
```

Please let me know, how i can get rid from the "[]" parenthesis after ajax response get.

Comment: simply do `response[0]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an array. Each {} is a returned record from your ajax.

Just loop through it like you would an array. If your ajax always only expects one result, then access the data using `result[0]` provided the response has already been properly parsed.

Comment: Can you tell me how i can send the data to google calendar api with specific timestamp.Actually, i am trying to send the data to the google calendar api but it is inserting event at tomorrow dates.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be coming in as an array with a single index, simply select the first index.

```
let response = ajaxrequest()[0]
```

This will 'extract' the first index.

Answer (score 0):

Add a check for when it comes as array.

```
result = Array.isArray(response) ? response [0] : response;
```